# Azure webapp cannot connect to mysql database on azure

Tags: mysql, eclipse, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying my jsp webapp to azure using eclipse azure plugin.JSP pages are successfully deployed but app cannot connect to mysql databse on azure.

Comment: Give a screenshot or some error message will be helpful.

Comment: When you publish app through eclipse, its connectionstring may be your local or sql database. So, if you want to connect the database on azure, you need to change the connection with your database on azure.